# hex to binary code error?

Tags: swift

So, i am trying to do a conversion with any value of the hexadecimal to binary but it seems my code doesn't accept 2f and etc. What am i doing wrong?

```
@IBOutlet weak var input: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var mylabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {

    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

@IBAction func getresults(_ sender: Any) {
    if Int(input.text!,radix:16) != nil
        let hex = String(Int(input.text!,radix:16)!, radix:2)
        mylabel.text = "The Hexadecimal of \(input.text!) conversion is:  \(hex)"
    }else{
        mylabel.text = "Wrong input"

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change your function to this... (I have also changed some variable names as they are currently a bit confusing)

```
@IBAction func getresults(_ sender: Any) {
    if let inputText = input.text, // 1
       let inputHex = Int(inputText, radix: 16) { // 2

        let binary = String(inputHex, radix: 2) // 3
        mylabel.text = "The Hexadecimal of \(inputText) conversion is:  \(binary)"
    }else{
        mylabel.text = "Wrong input"
    }
}
```

1. check that the input is not nil.
2. convert the input into a hex Int.

If any of the above fail show "Wrong input".

3. Convert the hex int into binary.

Then display the binary.

Using force unwrapping `!` is not recommended as it will crash your app if the value is `nil`. Using `if let` (optional binding) is a way to check if it is nil and bind the value to a non-optional variable instead.

Comment: Thank this helped me a lot.

Comment: @Dev1234 no worries, happy to help. Be sure to accept the correct answer. It shows that the question is solved for future users and gives back to the people answering :D And welcome to StackOverflow :D

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you check

```
if Int(input.text!) != nil
```

is to see if the input text is a valid integer - and it's not if it includes 2f

Instead of checking for a valid integer, you should check for valid hex

```
if Int(input.text!,radix:16) != nil
```

Comment: Checking for `nil` if the value is going to be used is pretty *unswifty* 

Comment: Thank you this helped me a lot.

Comment: i really don't use nil as much but i think i just got myself confused. @vadian

Comment: @Dev1234 The answer of Fogmeister is the recommended and most efficient way to handle the optionals.

Comment: your right thanks for the tips, i appreciate that one. @vadian